# Python Script to turn duplicate parts into instances

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, linked-data

Right now I am animating a model that is coming from cad software. However the model can only be exported as stl parts. meaning that I have something like 25,000 parts even though there are only like 100-200 unique parts. This makes the file something like 10gb which is too much to be rendered using a gpu.

I have found that I can grab all the parts that have the same name, link their object data to a single one and then purge the unused data to reduce the file size. But as I said before, there are 200 unique parts and 25,000 total parts, so selecting would take hours.

I am not new to coding but I am new to coding in python and blender.

So my question is how would I go about selecting items and linking object data through code?

I figure I have to search through the model tree for similar names, place them into a group and then iterate through it. But I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your duplicated objects share the same mesh ID, you can do <kbd>SHIFT+L -> Object Data</kbd> while initially selecting a singular mesh. This will select all objects that share the same mesh ID of the initially selected object.

[image]

The Python equivalent of the operator is this.

```py
bpy.ops.object.select_linked(type="OBDATA")
```